# COM script activation sometimes fails

Tags: c++, windows, vbscript, com

I am running com scripts from c++ on windows xp
Usually the script executes without problems, but sometimes the execution fails with hresult DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND. (Invoke is the function that fails)
Does anybody have any idea why it happens?
The code is below

```
CLSID clsid;   
MULTI_QI mqi;  
HRESULT hr ;  

mqi.hr = 0;  
mqi.pIID = &IID_IDispatch;  
mqi.pItf = NULL;  
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(T2W(progId.c_str()), &clsid);  
CHECK_HRESULT(hr);        

hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, 1, &mqi);  
CHECK_HRESULT(hr);        

tMethodArguments argTemp(arguments.size()) ;  
USES_CONVERSION ;  
HRESULT hr;  
DISPID index ;  
OLECHAR FAR*  szMember = T2W(method.c_str());   
unsigned int err ;  

hr = m_pScriptComObj->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &szMember, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &index ) ;  
CHECK_HRESULT(hr);  

DISPPARAMS  params ;  
params.rgvarg = pArgs ;  
params.rgdispidNamedArgs = NULL ;  
params.cArgs        = arguments.size() ;  
params.cNamedArgs   = 0 ;  

EXCEPINFO excep_info;  

hr = m_pScriptComObj->Invoke(index,
                  IID_NULL,
                  LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
                  DISPATCH_METHOD,
                  &params,
                  &res,
                  &excep_info,
                  &err);
```

I omitted  method and arguments initialization

The vbscript that is called by INVOKE looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component id="script_wsc_script">

<?component?>

<registration
    description="script_wsc_script"
    progid="wscScript.WSC"
    version="1.00"
    classid="{A1C14070-EBAB-41A0-BC9C-B4330A73437D}"
    remotable="true"
>
</registration>
<public>

    <method name="PrintMessage">
        <PARAMETER name="first"/>
        <PARAMETER name="second"/>

    </method>
</public>

<script language="VBScript">
<![CDATA[

Function PrintMessage ( first, second)

''do something
End Function
```

Comment: In general, this is a pretty normal mishap when you use late binding.  Does CHECK_HRESULT() actually throw an exception?  Is the member you are trying to invoke a property instead of a method?

Comment: @HansPassant The member i am trying to invoke is a method defined in vbscript. CHECK_HRESULT(hr) throws exception in case hr is an error.